# displaying login in magento 1.6

Tags: magento, layout, php

I am figuring out how to enable login.phtml in magento 1.6 only in **custom theme**, however, it is clear to me that in magento 1.6 login is triggered from persistent not from customer until persistent is switched off. I am not able to display it either in persistent or in customer layout settings. In a built-in or base theme it is working fine but since I am developing a custom theme and now I am stuck on it to work properly. Any help is highly appreciated....

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check with the related XMLs..

It do all the things in magento.

Comment: Thanks Sankar, Will u please throw some light to your answer as I have already gone through all related xmls but didn't find solution.